# How to add contact without using SaveContactTask in WP7 using C#

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

I use SaveContactTask but I can't insert a fax number in for the contact.

Comment: What's the main problem, Add contact without SaveContactTask? No Property to save Fax number? or Both?

Comment: There are two problems.. I want to add fax number but savecontacttask doesn't provide it so is there any alternative???  and while saving contact, is it possible to save contact without opening SaveContactTask API.. i.e. I want to save data directly from my page..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to save a contact in Windows Phone is to use the SaveContactTask. So if this task does not save a fax number, it's not possible.